# How to read data from file in server in byte array

Tags: java, android, file, bytebuffer

I want to read a file from a server and get the data of it.

I have written following piece of code.

```
URL uurl = new URL(this.m_FilePath);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uurl.openStream()));

String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    text_file=text_file+str;
    text_file=text_file+"\n";
}
m_byteVertexBuffer=text_file.getBytes();
```

But i am getting wrong result! If I read data from a string, I get m_bytevertexbuffer length=249664.

Now when I read a local file into the bytearray then i get m_bytevertexbuffer length=169332.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(VertexFile);
fis.read(m_byteVertexBuffer);

ByteBuffer dlb=null;

int l=m_byteVertexBuffer.length;
```

I want the same data in bytebuffer from a server and also from a local file!

Comment: To read bytes, read from the InputStream, and don't wrap it with a Reader. Your second piece of code doesn't make sense: it prints the length of a byte array, which is the same whether you have read or not from the file. Read the Java IO tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: in short i wanted to ask how i should read binary file placed in server?

Answer (score 0):

If the server sends a header `Content-Length: 999` you could allocate a `new byte[999]`.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
int contentLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
// -1 if not known or > int range.
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    //if (contentLength >= 0) {
    //    byte[] bytes = new byte[contentLength];
    //    in.read(bytes);
    //    m_byteVertexBuffer = bytes;
    //} else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[contentLength == -1 ? 10240 : contentLength];
        for (;;) {
            int nread = in.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            if (nread <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            baos.write(bytes, 0, nread);
        }
        m_byteVertexBuffer = baos.toByteArray();
    //}
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

In the general case you would use only the code of the else-branch. But still, one the presence of a valid content-length it is usable.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the read() method will read all the bytes at once. A loop should always be used.

Comment: @MuneemHabib try `in.close();`.

Comment: @MuneemHabib maybe there is an other problem: the writing not calling `close()` so the last part is now flushed, written.

Comment: sir its not reading full bytes i am also reading binary file from sdcard through file stream and it is working very fine but i am stuck in this problem i dont find any problem but it is not reading full bytes